# How to prevent Jquery click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

am using Html and Jquery in my Project
Project Demo [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/nh23cqbo/)

I have `<ul>` `radio buttons` in my HTML page as below

HTML Code

```
<ul class="featureBoxes paddingRight">
    <li class="featuresHeading features liListTo">
        <input type="radio"  id="selectProvider" class="rd" name="rdbToList" value="1" />
        <label for="selectProvider">
            Radio 1
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul class="featureListings ">
            <li>
                data 1
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>`
    <li class="featuresHeading options liListTo">
        <input type="radio"  id="selectPatient" class="rd" name="rdbToList"
            value="2" />
        <label for="selectPatient">
            Radio 2
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul class="featureListings">
            <li>
                <div id="sptDiv" style="padding: 2px 0px 2px 8px;">
                    Data 2
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="featuresHeading curtain-options liListTo">
        <input type="radio"  id="directEmail" class="rd" name="rdbToList"
            value="3">
        <label for="directEmail">
            Radio 3
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul class="featureListings ">
            <li>
                Data 2
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and I am using Jquery for this to `slideup` and `slide down`.
**Problem:** when I click on radio buttons lable it `slidedown` for few seconds and again `slideup` as in above fiddle.

JavaScript

```
$(function () {
    $("ul.featureListings").hide();
    $(".featuresHeading").click(function (event) {                    
        $(this).find('.rd').attr('checked', 'checked');
        if ($(this).find('.rd').is(':checked')) {
            $('ul.featureListings.demo').slideUp(300);
            $(this).find('.rd').attr('checked', 'checked');
            $('ul.featureListings.demo').not($(this).next().find('ul.featureListings')).removeClass("demo");
            if ($(this).next().find('ul.featureListings').hasClass("demo")) {
                $(this).next().find('ul.featureListings').removeClass("demo");
                $(this).next().find('ul.featureListings').slideUp(300);
            }
            else {
                $(this).next().find('ul.featureListings').addClass("demo");
                $(this).next().find('ul.featureListings').slideDown(300);
            }
        }
        //event.preventDefault();
        return true;
    });
});
```

Please give me suggestion how to prevent click event on `<ul>` and `radio buttons` ?

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/nh23cqbo/)

Comment: @lolka_bolka - I tried this but not working. Please visit the jsfiddle link will help you understanding the issue

Comment: it is because `return false;` includes `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: @Regent - I am not getting you. :( where should I change in my code?

Comment: @Regent - yes exactly. I want `li` should stay open and radio button should clicked

Comment: @Regent - It's not working when we click on radio buttons

Comment: Do you want it to work on clicking the radio button? or label? or you want to execute click on clicking either of them but only once?

Comment: @AhsanAyaz - I want both should work. when user click on radio button or lable it should slide down/up

Comment: @Prog take a look at [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nh23cqbo/19/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$("ul.featureListings").hide();
$(".featuresHeading [type=radio]").click(function (e) {

    $("ul.featureListings").slideUp();
    $(this).parent().next("li").find("ul").stop().slideDown(300);

});
```

NOTE: change click event to `radio button` not container. If you bind click event on container The click event `call two times` when using `label for` with radio button  :**[example](http://jsfiddle.net/nh23cqbo/21/)**.check when name is clicked  ,

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Bala_chandran/nh23cqbo/28/)

Comment: I seen you DEMO link- it's not working when we click on radio buttons.

Comment: Great..!! really cool ..it reduce my 80% code and working as perfect as I want ...Thanks a lot :)

Comment: With little animation changed ;)

Comment: Checkbox is not selected if I click on its label. And there is no slideDown if I click on selected item again.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.prop('checked', true)` instead of `.attr('checked', 'checked')` and dont handle "click" events from `<label>`. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dizel3d/pzx2wmbg)

```
$(function () {
                $("ul.featureListings").hide();
                $(".featuresHeading").click(function (event) {
                    if (event.target !== this && !$(event.target).is('input')) {
                        return;
                    }
                    $(this).find('.rd').prop('checked', true);
                    if ($(this).find('.rd').is(':checked')) {
                        $('ul.featureListings.demo').slideUp(300);
                        $(this).find('.rd').prop('checked', true);
                        $('ul.featureListings.demo').not($(this).next().find('ul.featureListings')).removeClass("demo");
                        if ($(this).next().find('ul.featureListings').hasClass("demo")) {
                            $(this).next().find('ul.featureListings').removeClass("demo");
                            $(this).next().find('ul.featureListings').slideUp(300);
                        }
                        else {
                            $(this).next().find('ul.featureListings').addClass("demo");
                            $(this).next().find('ul.featureListings').slideDown(300);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: radio buttons is not get selected in you above Example - Link